# How do I concatenate strings with chars in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char, string-concatenation

I've got a function which takes a string, let's call it

```
void print(std::string myString) 
{ 
    std::cout << myString;
}
```

I want to do something like

```
char myChar;
myChar = '{';
print("Error, unexpected char: " + myChar + "\n");
```

It doesn't work.

I tried something like

```
print(std::string("Error, unexpected char") + std::string(myChar) + std::string("\n) )
```

but then std::string(myChar) becomes whatever int the char represents, it's printed as an int and isn't printed as it's alphanumeric representation!

Comment: Did you try : `std::string("Error, unexpected char") + ch`?

Comment: There is no constructor of `std::string` which converts a char  into its digits. Did you perhaps use `std::to_string`?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk i did, but i wanted the newline in there instead of putting it in  my print function. Also, yeah I used tostring forgot sorry

Comment: If `... +ch+"\n" `doesn't work, then the newline can be written as: `"\n"s `

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks *it's printed as an int and isn't printed as it's alphanumeric representation!* -- I'm surprised no one so far has actually explained the issue. You used the wrong `std::string` constructor.  It should have been `std::string(1, myChar);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should be declared like:

```
void print( const std::string &myString) 
{ 
    std::cout << myString;
}
```

and called like:

```
print( std::string( "Error, unexpected char: " ) + myChar + "\n");
```

As for your comment:

> as a follow up, would it have been possible to pass an anonymous
> function returning a string as an argument to print()? Something like
> print( {return "hello world";}

then you can do this as it is shown in the demonstration program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f( std::string h() )
{
    std::cout << h() << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    f( []()->std::string { return "Hello World!"; } );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works! Looks like what I did wrong was passing print(std::string("Unexpected Character " + character) + '\n') as the argument, i should have kept the literal and character separate

Comment: as a follow up, would it have been possible to pass an anonymous function returning a string as an argument to print()? Something like print( [](){return "hello world";})

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks Here you are  #include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f( std::string h() )
{
 std::cout << h() << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
 f( []()->std::string { return "Hello World!"; } );
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: Thanks! So I have to declare an overload to accept a lambda each time? Is there a way to automatically accept lambdas for any argument by default?

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks If types of lambda expressions converted to functions are different then you have to declare a template function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++14, you can do this:

```cpp
using namespace std::literals;
char myChar;
myChar = '{';
print("Error, unexpected char: "s + myChar + "\n"s);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to c++ so didn't know you could make string literals, thought u always had char array literals

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any one and concat.

You can use `str.c_str()` to convert C++ string to C character array.

Or

Use  std::string inbuilt constructor to convert C character array to C++ string.